# Почему если попытаться заполнить пустой массив в цикле - все ссылки внутри него остаются null?

Tags: java, массивы

Почему если попытаться заполнить пустой массив в цикле - все ссылки внутри него остаются null?

Создаю массив размерностью 3 типа String. Использую расширенный for, прохожу по каждой ссылку присваивая ей ссылку на строку. В итоге, получаю все равно массив с элементами null

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       String[] arr = new String[3];
       for (String i : arr){
           i = "AAA";
       }

       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

В консоль будет выведено [null, null, null]

-Если цикл заменить на цикл for(int i=0;i<3;i++), в таком случае все работает корректно.

Comment: Потому что в цикле вы получаете копию ссылки на объект. Присвоив этой переменной что-то другое, ничего не поменяется. Аналогично и с параметрами в методах